# How to identify owner of lost iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

Let's say I lost my phone. If the person that finds that phone wants to return it, how would they be able to locate me? How to display my contact details and/or a custom message on the lock screen? Are there other ways to *tag* the phone with your details in case such event takes place?

Assume the person that finds it knows how to use a smartphone but is not a tech expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a message to Lost Mode, informing 'honest finders' of how to contact you. See - [iCloud: Use Lost Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2700)

It's also possible to add text to your lock screen [We have that on both my & my partner's lock screen images, just in case either of us walks under a bus... which of course would not be a 'lost mode' situation]

I've been trying to Google some ideal lock screen info - but they all seem to be based on apps... all you really need is to know the screen size of your current lock screen image, add the text in Photoshop or Gimp etc & set as your new lock screen :/

[This](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2016/06/21/how-to-change-the-iphone-lock-screen/) gives a decent general overview of how to change your lockscreen, but what you really need are the sizes, so you can make one with the '3D' view or just static - [this page](http://www.cultofmac.com/410790/how-to-create-perfectly-sized-iphone-and-ipad-wallpapers-with-pixelmator-for-ios/) has a guide to image sizes [ignore that they're trying to sell you an app to do it, any image editor can do this].

This is my lock-screen...

[image]

Comment: To clarify, when you say that "[i]t's also possible to add text to your lock screen", you mean by modifying the lock screen wallpaper and not through some hidden setting?

Comment: Yes, literally overlay it with something legible - if you get knocked down by a bus you want the emergency services to be able to see your ICE details without needing to unlock your phone. Added example to answer.

Comment: The Health app has this Medical ID setting where you can select your emergency contact from your contacts list. That person's name and phone number is then displayed in the lock screen but to reach it you have to slide left, click emergency and then click Medical ID. So not exactly easy to find. I think I'll follow your answer and modify my original wallpaper and add a text message so it is always displayed during lock. Thank you for the example!