# iMessage shows ICE instead of contact

Tags: messages, contacts.app

I am trying to have an iMessage conversation with my family, but instead of showing their name it shows "ICE" because that same number is listed in my In Case of Emergency (ICE) contact. Is there anyway to change it so it shows their name not "ICE"

Comment: What does the person's name look like in your Contacts? Does it say their name, or ICE?

Comment: There are two separate contacts. One says their name, the other says "ICE"

Comment: Does your phone have a passcode lock?  While the ICE contact was once a good idea, most phones can't be opened by emergency personnel these days due to passcodes.

Comment: Yes, delete their ICE contact. I don't know that there's any concrete data on which of two contacts iOS will choose if they have identical phone numbers, but the easiest way is to use the built-in ICE function in the Health app and remove the redundant ICE contact.

Comment: Alternative to the Health app, which as @tubedogg says is difficult to find - actually overlay your lock screen image with the information - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246256/85275

Answer (score 4):

iPhones have a neat feature that allows you to put your emergency contact information on the lock screen so no one has to unlock your phone to access it. You can set it up [through the Health App on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203037).

Since your Contacts won't be accessible on your iPhone without your passcode, this is a reasonable alternative.

If you set this up, you could theoretically delete the entry in your Contacts that is listed as ICE, thereby fixing your problem with the contact name showing up as ICE.

Comment: Adding Emergency info to the health app for the lock screen is a great idea - but suffers one potentially fatal flaw - it requires the person first on the scene to ***know exactly how to look for it***. Adding your details manually to your lockscreen picture is far easier for someone to find.

Comment: Knew I'd posted it as an answer somewhere... http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246256/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin: Adding a graphic with text to the lock screen is a great option. I just wanted the OP author to recognize that they did not need to have a contact labeled "ICE." You can't access a locked phone anyway. (Now I'm off to put contact info on a graphic...)

Comment: for sure. We used to have ICE entries, but suffered the same as the OP. We actually switched to the overlay method before the Health app option came to iOS, but have stuck with it for its simplicity. I do assume ambulance crews know how to find that info, but most ordinary folks, I doubt it... It also covers as a contact for an honest finder of the phone, if lost.

Comment: I had an emergency situation arise. I opened the ICE on the lock screen myself and handed it to the doctor. It had my allergies and conditions on it, so they could make quick decisions. I don't think the average person knows how to access it, though... You're absolutely right.

Comment: While "the average person" may not know, given the popularity of iPhones I'd be surprised if paramedics/emergency personnel weren't aware of this feature (or at very least didn't stumble upon it when fiddling with the phone in order to try and find some useful information).  After all, all they need do is press the big "Emergency" button when at the unlock screen and then the big red "Medical ID" button...