# Put owner information on iPhone lock screen (via provisioning profile) without wiping device?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-lock

Is there a way to setup a device as managed or whatever in order to put owner information on the lock screen without wiping the whole phone? Or, can you at least restore from a prior/unrelated backup afterward?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but this is how I make sure my Emergency info is legible even to people who don't know how to access the 'proper' emergency info on an iPhone - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246252/how-to-identify-owner-of-lost-iphone/246256#246256

Comment: I've done that before, but it doesn't work well with Parallax. There's a built-in way using iOS 10, but it requires provisioning/managed device configuration.

Comment: A bit of trial & error was all it took to make mine 'parallax-safe'. A dark vignette helped too.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just add the owner information to whatever wallpaper image you're using?  There's no need for an overly technical solution.

Comment: Because there is a clean, built-in way to do it that's better designed. However it requires setting up in advance.